# Is the covering efficiency relation transitive?

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, order-theory, partitions

Let $X\neq \emptyset$ be a set, let $\text{Part}(X)$ be the set of partitions of $X$ (where we require that $\emptyset \notin P$ whenever $P\in\text{Part}(X)$).

For $P, Q\in \text{Part}(X)$ we say that $P$ *covers* $X$ *more efficiently* than $Q$ if $$\text{card}(P\setminus Q) < \text{card}(Q\setminus P), $$ and we write $P<_{\text{eff}}Q$ for this.

Is $<_{\text{eff}}$ transitive?

Comment: Since $P-Q=P-(P\cap Q)$ and $Q-P=Q-(P\cap Q)$, what you are really saying is ${\rm card}(P)<{\rm card}(Q)$ (since you are taking the same number of parts out of both partitions, namely ${\rm card}(P\cap Q)$).  Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @PaceNielsen I guess it is not exactly the same thing.  For example, take $X=\mathbb{N}, P=\{1,2\}, \{3\}, \{4\}, \dots$, and $Q=\{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\}, \dots$.  Then $P < Q$, but $P$ and $Q$ have the same cardinality.

Comment: @TonyHuynh Thanks.  For some reason I was thinking finite sets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the answer is yes.  Let $X\neq \emptyset$ and let $P,Q,R\in {\rm Part}(X)$.

First, note that if $|P|<|Q|$, then $P<_{\rm eff}Q$, since $|P-Q|\leq |P|<|Q|=|Q-P|$.

Now we are ready for the proof.  Assume $P<_{\rm eff}Q<_{\rm eff}R$.  Without loss of generality, we may remove $P\cap Q\cap R$ from all the sets, and reduce to the case that $P\cap Q\cap R=\emptyset$.  By our previous paragraph, we also have $|P|\leq |Q|\leq |R|$.  If inequality holds anywhere, then we have $P<_{\rm eff}R$ and we are done.  Assume the contrary case holds, and so all three sets have equal cardinality.  Note that $|P|$ must be infinite, else the computation from my comment above applies.

From the fact that $|P-Q|<|Q-P|$ and $|P|=|Q|$, we see that $|P\cap Q|=|P|=|Q|$.  Now because $(P\cap Q)\cap R=\emptyset$, we have $|Q-R|\geq |P\cap Q|=|Q|=|R|\geq |R-Q|$, contradicting the fact that $Q<_{\rm eff}R$.  Thus, this contrary case cannot actually happen after all.

Comment: Great answer and easy to understand -- thanks Pace!